# Hide keyboard when checkbox in ListView is clicked

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-softkeyboard

I currently have ListView where each Item has a TextView and a CheckBox. On top of the ListView is an EditText to search the ListView. When a user has searched something and clicks one of the CheckBoxes or scrolls in the list of given results, I'd like the keyboard to go away. How can I do this?

I've handled the keyboard in my other activities using the InputMethodManager, but I can't call it inside the adapter because the EditText is outside its scope and I can't call it in the activity using the adapter because as far as it's concerned nothing's changing when clicking the CheckBox.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Pass an interface to your adapter

```
class MyActivity {
      public interface OnCheckBoxClickListener{
          public void OnCheckboxClicked();
      }

      public class MyOnCheckBoxClickListener :OnCheckBoxClickListener {

          private WeakReference<Context> mContext;

          public MyOnCheckBoxClickListener(Context context){
                 mContext = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
          }

          public void OnCheckboxClicked(){
          Context context = null;
          mContext.TryGetTarget(out context);

          var editText = (context as Activity).FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edittextId);
          editText.ClearFocus();
          }
      }

      YourListAdapter adapter = new YourListAdapter(new MyOnCheckBoxClickListener(this)); 
}
```

2) Then in your adapter:

```
    class YourListAdapter {

    OnCheckBoxClickListener mListener;

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
            //code for view generation
            var checkbox = convertView.FindViewById<Checkbox>(Resource.Id.YourCheckbox);
            checkbox.Click += (sender, args) => {
                mListener.OnCheckboxClicked();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also you can achieve same thing using delegates.

Comment: What code should I use to dismiss the keyboard then? Normally I use (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService (Context.InputMethodService) but I can't use it since there is no Context.

Comment: You create interface in your activity, then you pass it to Adapter constructor

Comment: It says I can't use += operator on a boolean

Comment: It is my mistake. Not ".Selected", but ".Click". I'll edit code again

Comment: Ok, I'm getting there. Now I just need to figure out how to get the current focus. I can't get this out of the context I presume?

Comment: Cast Context to Activity, and find your EditText with FindViewById

Comment: Great, that was it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great it helped. Do not miss WeakReference, or you will have memory leak!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more so I understand for the future?

Comment: Basically, you will have Strong reference in you adapter to your activity and activity will have strong reference to your adapter, both of them will never be cleared by GC. You can read more at http://www.dotnetperls.com/weakreference

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function when you need to hide keyboard.

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        view.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

You can use it on listView:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        hideKeyboard();
    }
});
```

Or checkBox:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hideKeyboard();
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But I can't call this.getCurrentFocus() inside the adapter.

Comment: Then you need to pass Context to your adapter

Comment: I don't think this is best practice, is it?

Comment: Use `View view = ((Activity) mContext).getCurrentFocus();` and all will work.